# How do I disable the redirect to Skype when I click "call via iPhone" in safari?

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, skype, call

I installed Skype because I need it and it auto-routes the click to call function to Skype now on my MacBook (Catalina 10.15.6).

How do I disable the routing to Skype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to FaceTime -> Preferences. There, change "default for calls" (or something like it, my Mac is in dutch) to FaceTime.